# How will search suggestion overlap in map view

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-adapter, android-adapterview

I have search view that looks like below which doesn't overlap the search suggestion.  Like:

[What I currently Have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2kU3.png)

However, I want the search suggestion overlap above the map.
Like:

[Here's what I w ant to achieve](https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview/raw/master/images/1506tq.gif)

Code:

```
   searchView = (MaterialSearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            //Do some magic
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            searchView.setSuggestions(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.query_suggestions));
            return false;
        }
    });

    searchView.setOnSearchViewListener(new MaterialSearchView.SearchViewListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSearchViewShown() {
            //Do some magic
        }

        @Override
        public void onSearchViewClosed() {
            //Do some magic
        }
    });
```

Here is the XML. I have no clue if the problem is here for any solution

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Also, is there a way for me to attach the search suggestion to

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> vehicle;
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.journerytech.mark.mark.activity.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

            <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
                android:id="@+id/search_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: where is the image

Comment: Hi Jins, I need 2 rep. to post image. I did set it on above hyperlink.

Comment: can you show me map layout

Comment: `https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2kU3.png` when search suggestions show it go directly below the search bar and doesn't overlap the map. Worst thing is when search suggestion show it does get/brought one full width of the image that moves the map below/down.

Comment: i think this is xml layout problem

Comment: Hi Jins, I am too, but do you have solution for this problem?